# Ionic 5 ipone 10+ on session or id not saving in localstorage

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have devloped app in ionic 5, now I am build in ios, my app working fine on iphone 6 version but
iphone 10+ vesions on not save the session my app is login and again back to logout if any solution  so please reply me.

Thnak you.

I want to expect app session is continue to login mode if user click on logout then app is logout another is open to login mode.